Does hydrogen peroxide work as a rocket fuel oxidizer by itself?
Suppose an aerospace company is building a rocket engine. Their fuel is isopropanol. They don't have access to LOX or another common oxidizer, and the engine cannot be air-breathing. They only have hydrogen peroxide ($\require{mhchem}\ce{H_2O_2}$). Would hydrogen peroxide, when mixed with and ignited in an isopropanol solution, oxidize the fuel and allow it to burn? If no, why not?
I think I should note that I do not intend to attempt this. It's out of pure curiosity.

The aerospace acronym is "HTP" for High-test peroxide

Turns out we have a whole hydrogen-peroxide tag. Have a look about the site, we've got some good stuff here

Hydrogen peroxide just needs a catalyst, like silver or platinum, as used by rocket powered dragsters.  I don't think this would be efficient enough to use for an actual rocket (low thrust to mass | volume ratio compared to other fuels actually used in rockets).

@rcgldr slightly related to that: Does the Soyuz spacecraft use chemically stabilized hydrogen peroxide (H₂O₂) to remain ISS-dockable for 200+ days?

@rcgldr What if it's not supposed to be an orbital vehicle? What if it's just a low-altitude sounding rocket?

@AustinOverton - I don't know all of the applications of H2O2 being used as a rocket fuel. For space launches, first stage is often kerosene due to thrust energy versus volume ratio versus hydrogen + oxygen that would require too much volume for a first stage, but have better thrust energy to mass ratio for the other stages.

Yes, hydrogen peroxide works as an oxidizer with hydrocarbon and hydrazine fuels.
The raw specific impulse of peroxide-based combinations is generally lower than LOX with the same fuels (e.g Hydrazine/LOX = 312 sec, Hydrazine/H2O2 = 286 sec, about 8% difference), but it is relatively dense, about 27% denser than LOX.
I haven't found a specific impulse figure for the isopropanol/H2O2 combination, but the specific impulse of isopropanol/LOX is nearly as good as the very common kerosene/LOX combination (341 sec vs 347 sec, from another source). I would guess isopropanol/H2O2 is similarly close to kerosene/H2O2.
Because of its density, the kerosene-hydrogen-peroxide combination has been considered as an oxidizer for reusable single-stage-to-orbit spacecraft, since denser propellants implies smaller tanks, a smaller craft, and less mass needed for heat shielding, and lowered specific impulse actually has a paradoxical effect of faster increase in acceleration, shortening time to orbit and thus the fraction of performance spent fighting gravity.
There's some additional information about the use of hydrogen peroxide in rocketry in another Q/A on this site, which may be of interest.

Trying to find the video of Armadillo Aerospace testing HTP with various materials and finding out it aggressively oxidized the leather shoes somebody (maybe Carmack?) was prone to wearing, but stumbled across your past related answer instead
